# How to get adjacent vertices of a vertex? (with Python)

Tags: python, edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools, edges

How can I get a list of vertices that share edge with a given vertex over script? I need this to work in edit mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [BMEdge.other_vert](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMEdge.other_vert)

This script runs in edit-mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for v in bm.verts:
    for e in v.link_edges:
        v_other = e.other_vert(v)

        # print some info
        print("%d -> %d via edge %d" % (v.index, v_other.index, e.index))
```